# action script sort xml feed by order it appears

Tags: xml, actionscript-2

I have adapted the following script, I would like to remove the random script and instead change it so that it appears in the order of the xml feed, I've tried but nothing works for me.

I need to modify this line: `_global.song_nr = random(songfile.length);`

full script

```
    playlist.onLoad = function(success) {
    if (success) {
        _global.songname = [];
        _global.songband = [];
        _global.songimg = [];
        _global.songdate = [];
        _global.songfile = [];
        for (var i = 0; i<playlist.firstChild.childNodes.length; i++) {
            _global.songname[i] = playlist.firstChild.childNodes[i].attributes.name;
            _global.songband[i] = playlist.firstChild.childNodes[i].attributes.artist;
            _global.songimg[i] = playlist.firstChild.childNodes[i].attributes.img;
            _global.songdate[i] = playlist.firstChild.childNodes[i].attributes.date;
            _global.songfile[i] = playlist.firstChild.childNodes[i].attributes.file;
            trace(songname[i]+"  "+songband[i]+"  "+songimg[i]+"  "+songdate[i]+"  "+songfile[i]);
        }
    }
    _root.createEmptyMovieClip("sound_mc", 1);
    _root.sound_mc.sound_obj = new Sound();
    _global.song_nr = random(songfile.length);
    _root.sound_mc.songStarter(songfile[song_nr], songname[song_nr], songband[song_nr], songimg[song_nr], songdate[song_nr]);
};
```

Comment: actionscript 2, _root, _global ...sounds like fun :P try _global.song_nr = 0; or _global.song_nr = songfile.length-1; to get the first or last value, depending on how your feed is setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @GeorgeProfenza this works - simple :)

```
_global.song_nr = 0;
```